# Performance with Fluent Validator

Tags: c#, .net, fluentvalidation

I'd like to try the .NET [FluentValidation](https://github.com/JeremySkinner/FluentValidation) library for form input validation on an upcoming project. In looking over the documentation, I came across this:

**A note on performance**

`Instantiation of validators is an expensive process due to the expression tree compilation and parsing within the RuleFor definitions. Because of this, it's recommended that you use validator instances as singletons- once instantiated they should be cached and reused, rather than being instantiated multiple times. Validators do not contain any shared state, so it should also be safe to reuse them in multithreaded scenarios too.`

`The best approach to caching the validator instances would be to use an IoC container (eg, StructureMap) to manage the instance lifecycles.`

I don't know what this means? Can somebody help?

Answer (score 3):

They recommend only instantiating an implementation of a validator once, either at application startup (eager) or when first required (lazy). The most common way of achieving this is using a singleton pattern. For more information about this particular pattern in C#, you can go to [C# in Depth - Singletons](http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/General/Singleton.aspx).

The easier way of managing validators is the use of an IoC container, such as Ninject, Castle Windsor, Unity, etc, as they allow you to just specify a dependency registration as having a singleton lifecycle.